Not able to send Message from Dotnet WebSocket but can receive it
I have a dotnet core app. Below is my web socket code for it
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
IConfiguration configuration = builder.Configuration;
builder.Services.AddCors();
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseMiddleware<WebSocketMiddleware>();
app.Run();

public class WebSocketMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next = next;

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                await HandleWebSocket(webSocket);
            }
            else
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
        }

        private static async Task HandleWebSocket(WebSocket webSocket)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              
                WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

                while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
                {
                    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {message}");

                    // Echo the message back to the client
                    await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
                    // Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                }

                await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"WebSocket error: {ex.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                webSocket.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

This is my front-end NextJS code
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessage] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5114");

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.onopen = function (event) {
      console.log("Connected to WebSocket server");
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log("Received message:", event.data);
      setMessage((oldArray) => [...oldArray, event.data]);
    };

    socket.onclose = function (event) {
      console.log("WebSocket connection closed");
    };
  }, []);

  const onChangeHandler = (event: any) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <input type="text" onChange={onChangeHandler} value={input} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("here");
          // socket.emit("messageFromClient", { data: input });
          socket.send(input);
        }}>
        Submit
      </button>
      {messages.map((item, index) => {
        return <h5 key={`${index}`}>{item}</h5>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

I am able too connect to my dotnet backend and when I send a message from client I can see it in my backend console but what I don't understand is why I am not able to send the message from my backend to the client
What am I missing?

do the incoming frames appear in your browser's network view? it is a little odd to mirror the message-type and EOM from the client, but I guess in your case it is an echo, so just about reasonable; minor note: if you haven't checked for EOM on the inbound, it isn't strictly legal to try to decode it - for example, in the case of UTF8 you could have a single multi-byte character split over two frames; however, in reality you're likely to be dealing with single-frame messages (i.e. EOM is always true). But the first thing to check: do the inbound frames appear in the browser's network view?

@MarcGravell What is inbound frame?

the browser's network tab usually shows individual web-socket frames; in the context of a client (the browser), an inbound frame is the server-to-client message; here's the outbound (client-to-server) frames for my stackoverflow session: https://i.sstatic.net/Vx5g5.png - the inbound frames (there just aren't any at the moment) would have the arrow pointing downwards; so: are there any server-to-client frames showing in the browser's network tools? edit: turns out me posting my comment causes an inbound: https://i.sstatic.net/CoVNa.png

@MarcGravell Here's the image when I send a "Hi" message from client side https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproject-a33f6.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%202024-04-10%20at%203.02.32%E2%80%AFPM.png?alt=media&token=980b0b12-b13b-4ea4-a14b-e5a2018f5fd6

OK, you can see in that image that your echo did exactly what you expect, so: we can ignore server-side : the server is working fine; this is a client-side only problem with your js code

It's true, there's no problem with backend.

@QiangFu Thanks I am checking on the client side, what could be the issue

Your WebSocket Server code is fine. I modified your client to ensure that only one instance of Websocket is running per browser instance. Try this code:
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    //const [messages, setMessage] = useState<string[]>([]);    
    const [messages, setMessage] = useState([]);    
    const socket = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        socket.current = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5114");
        socket.current.onopen = function (event) {
            console.log("Connected to WebSocket server");
        };

        /*
        socket.onmessage = function (event) {
            console.log("Received message:", event.data);            
            setMessage((oldArray) => [...oldArray, event.data]);        
        };
        */

        
        socket.current.onclose = function (event) {
            console.log("WebSocket connection closed");            
        };

        socket.current.onerror = () => {
            console.log("WebSocket error!");
        };

        return () => {
            console.log("Cleanup!");
            if (socket.current?.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                console.log("close websocket");
                socket.current.close();
            }
        }
    }, []);
    

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!socket.current) return;
        socket.current.onmessage = function (event) {
            const _data = event.data;
            console.log("Received message:", _data);
            setMessage((oldArray) => [...oldArray, _data]);
        };
    }, []);



    const onChangeHandler = (event) => {        
        setInput(event.target.value);
    };
    

    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
          <input type="text" onChange={onChangeHandler} value={input} />
          <button
              onClick={() => {
                  console.log("send to server: " + input);
                  //socket.emit("messageFromClient", { data: input });
                  socket.current.send(input);
              }}>
              Submit
            </button>
            {
                messages.map((item, index) => {
                    return <h5 key={`${index}`}>{item}</h5>;
                })
            }
      </div>     

  );



}

